# Question about View as Type Constraint in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, generics, swiftui

I am trying to create a class called Lesson. Each Lesson object should contain a different lesson page (a view) so that each lesson card can navigate to a different page.

The code for class Lesson is below:

```
class Lesson<T: View>: Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    var lessonName: String
    var lessonPage: T
    
    init(lessonName: String,
         lessonPage: T = DefaultLessonPageView() as! T) {
        self.lessonName = lessonName
        self.lessonPage = lessonPage
    }
}
```

The problem is that errors occurred while compiling code below:

```
struct ButtonPageView: View {
    var lesson: Lesson<View>

    var body: some View {
        NavigationLink(destination: lesson.lessonPage()) {
            some view here
        }
    }
}
```

The error is below:

> Value of protocol type 'View' cannot conform to 'View'; only struct/enum/class types can conform to protocols

What should I do to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With generics we should remember that types are inferred at compiled type, so views should be known at the moment expression written. So SwiftUI uses builder pattern for this purpose.

Here is a demo how it could be solved with support for generic page and some default one provided.

Tested with Xcode 12.4 / iOS 14.4

```
class Lesson<T: View>: Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    var lessonName: String

    var builder: (() -> T)?    // << optional builder
    
    @ViewBuilder
    func lessonPage() -> some View {   // ViewBuilder gives possibility
        if let page = builder?() {     // to provide default view
            page
        } else {
            DefaultLessonPageView()
        }
    }
    
    init(lessonName: String,
         lessonPage: (() -> T)? = nil) {  // by default no view
        self.lessonName = lessonName
        self.builder = lessonPage
    }
}

struct ButtonPageView<Page: View>: View {
    var lesson: Lesson<Page>

    var body: some View {
        NavigationLink(destination: lesson.lessonPage()) {
            Text("")
        }
    }
}
```

and now we can use those as

```
var body: some View {
    // no view, so let compiler know
    ButtonPageView<Never>(lesson: Lesson(lessonName: "First"))

    // page type is inferred from builder
    ButtonPageView(lesson: Lesson(lessonName: "Second", lessonPage: {
        Text("Second Lesson")
    }))
}
```